# Strawberry Haagen Dazs: The favored flavor of anime murderers?

Tags: tropes, the-garden-of-sinners, kite

Has anyone noticed how certain anime regarding murder and death that there is usually a reference to Haagen Dazs in there somewhere? Strawberry Haagen Dazs to be specific.

In certain anime, such as *Kara no Kyokai* episode 5 where the main character tends to eat nothing but strawberry Haagen Dazs. In *Kite*, there is one of them there is a subtle reference in a background scene. Then it *Kite Liberator*, the main character kept a fridge full of them.

So can someone tell me where this reference comes from or where it started or if they are connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Kite*, it's merely a parody reference, with the "[Häagen Kazs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkLmE.jpg)" name.

In *Kite Liberator*, it's also a parody, with the "[Hëegen-Gezs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=b6X40p1LkqY#t=3s)" name (Vanilla flavor in this case).

The ice cream is prominently stated to be Häagen-Dazs in both the *Kara no Kyoukai* movies and the [original novel](http://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Kara_no_Kyoukai:Chapter01_01#haag).

Shiki and her fridge can also be seen with several [bottles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE4Ce.jpg) of [Volvic water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plXMu.jpg).

These internationally well-known brands are probably so viewers could better identify with them (as they've probably had them in the past).

The ice cream is most likely being used as a foil to the the main character, highlighting them to be naive, childish (small, like the containers), and cold at the same time. The water, too, might be a foil of how Shiki has changed (melted slightly), but still remains cold.